# React Navigation linking initialRouteName not working when opening app from quit state

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I have followed the documentation of React Navigation and implemented an authentication flow as well the Linking mechanism for notifications via the linking prop of NavigationContainer.

When I open a notification when the app is running, e.g. the link https://domain/transactions/history, I am redirected to the screen TransactionHistory, and when I go back I am redirected to ChargingStations (as I want)
But, when I do the same thing from a quit state, I am being redirected as well but I can't go back to ChargingStations and I see the warning (The action GO_BACK was not handled by any navigator)..

My code is a follow:

App.tsx

```
export default class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  public state: State;
  public props: Props;
  public centralServerProvider: CentralServerProvider;
  public deepLinkingManager: DeepLinkingManager;
  private appVersion: CheckVersionResponse;
  private readonly navigationRef: React.RefObject<NavigationContainerRef<ReactNavigation.RootParamList>>;
  private readonly appContext;
  private initialUrl: string;

  public constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.navigationRef = React.createRef();
    this.appContext = {
      handleSignIn: () => this.setState({isSignedIn: true}),
      handleSignOut: () => this.setState({isSignedIn: false})
    };
    this.state = {
      switchTheme: false,
      navigationState: null,
      showAppUpdateDialog: false,
      isSignedIn: undefined
    };
  }

  public setState = (
    state: State | ((prevState: Readonly<State>, props: Readonly<Props>) => State | Pick<State, never>) | Pick<State, never>,
    callback?: () => void
  ) => {
    super.setState(state, callback);
  };


  public async componentDidMount() {
    // Get the central server
    this.centralServerProvider = await ProviderFactory.getProvider();

    // Setup notifications
    await Notifications.initialize();

    // Check for app updates
    this.appVersion = await Utils.checkForUpdate();
    // Set
    this.setState({
      showAppUpdateDialog: !!this.appVersion?.needsUpdate,
      isSignedIn: true
    });
  }

  public render() {
    const { switchTheme, showAppUpdateDialog, isSignedIn } = this.state;
    return switchTheme ? (
      <NativeBaseProvider>
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          {showAppUpdateDialog && (
            <AppUpdateDialog appVersion={this.appVersion} close={() => this.setState({ showAppUpdateDialog: false })} />
          )}
          {isSignedIn == null ?
            <Loading />
            :
            this.createRootNavigator()
          }
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
      </NativeBaseProvider>
    ) : (
      <NativeBaseProvider>
        <View />
      </NativeBaseProvider>
    );
  }

  private buildLinking(): LinkingOptions<ReactNavigation.RootParamList> {
    return (
      {
        prefixes: DeepLinkingManager.getAuthorizedURLs(),
        getInitialURL: () => this.initialUrl,
        subscribe: (listener) => {
          // Listen for background notifications when the app is running,
          const removeBackgroundNotificationListener = messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async (remoteMessage: Notification) => {
            const canHandleNotification = await Notifications.canHandleNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage);
            if (canHandleNotification) {
              this.setState({isSignedIn: true}, () => listener(remoteMessage.data.deepLink));
            }
          });
          return () => {
            removeBackgroundNotificationListener();
          };
        },
        config: {
          screens: {
            AuthNavigator: {
              screens: {
                Login: 'login'
              }
            },
            AppDrawerNavigator: {
              initialRouteName: 'ChargingStationsNavigator', // <-- Initial screen I would like to always be present as first screen when navigating
              screens: {
                ChargingStationsNavigator: {
                  initialRouteName: 'ChargingStations',
                  screens: {
                    ChargingStations: 'charging-stations/all'
                  }
                },
                InvoicesNavigator: 'invoices',
                TransactionInProgressNavigator: {
                  screens: {
                    TransactionsInProgress: 'transactions/inprogress'
                  }
                },
                TransactionHistoryNavigator: {
                  screens: {
                    TransactionsHistory: 'transactions/history'
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }

  private createRootNavigator() {
    const { isSignedIn } = this.state;
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={this.appContext}>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <NavigationContainer
            onReady={() => this.onReady()}
            linking={this.buildLinking()}
            ref={this.navigationRef}
            onStateChange={(newState) => this.setState({navigationState: newState})}
            initialState={this.state.navigationState}
          >
            <rootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="AuthNavigator" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
              {isSignedIn ?
                <rootStack.Screen name="AppDrawerNavigator" children={createAppDrawerNavigator} />
                :
                <rootStack.Screen options={{animationTypeForReplace: 'pop'}} name="AuthNavigator" children={createAuthNavigator} />
              }
            </rootStack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Expected behavior

I expect the ChargingStations screen to always be present as first screen, even from a quit state

#### Reproduction

https://github.com/sap-labs-france/ev-mobile/tree/upgrade_react_native

#### Platform

- [X] Android
- [X] iOS

#### Environment

- [x] I've removed the packages that I don't use

| package | version |
| --- | --- |
| @react-navigation/native | 6.0.14 |
| @react-navigation/drawer | 6.5.1 |
| @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs | 6.2.5 |
| @react-navigation/stack | 6.3.5 |
| react-native-safe-area-context | 4.4.1 |
| react-native-screens | 3.18.2 |
| react-native-gesture-handler | 2.8.0 |
| react-native-reanimated | 2.13.0 |
| react-native | 0.70.6 |
| node | 16.13.0 |
| npm or yarn | 9.1.2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to obtain the desired behavior by using following code in the drawer navigator props.

```js
backBehavior={'initialRoute'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a nested linking route: [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#handling-nested-navigators)

```js
const config = {
  screens: {
    Home: {
      screens: {
        Profile: 'users/:id',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```
                TransactionHistoryNavigator: {
                  screens: {
                    ChargingStationsNavigator: {
                      screens: {
                        TransactionsHistory: 'transactions/history'
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
```

Maybe you can try to redeclare initial route (unfortunately I have currently no access to verify my suggestion):

```
                TransactionHistoryNavigator: {
                  screens: {
                    TransactionsHistory: {
                     initialRouteName: 'ChargingStationsNavigator', //Define initial route here
                    }
                  }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I don't think you read my snippet correctly. I have posted my linking config object, and the structure is not as suggested

Comment: I think you can‘t go back cause you are on the top level of the Drawer, that‘s why you need to define a nested route.

Comment: But the purpose of initialRouteName is precisely to be able to have an initial screen. In the doc, the initialScreen used is a sibling, not a parent

Comment: So you would suggest nesting all of the siblings of ChargingStations inside it in the config, even if they are at the same level in the navigation structure ?

Comment: It looks like that initialRouteName behaves rather than a defaultRouteName. I try to provide an example.